# Sqlite unrecognized token: "'''"

Tags: python, sqlite

I met problems while using sqlite3 in python.

```
def getEntryId(self, table, field, value, createNew=True):
    cur=self.con.execute("select rowid from %s where %s = '%s'" % (table, field, value))
    res=cur.fetchone()
    if res==None:
        cur=self.con.execute("insert into %s (%s) values('%s') " % (table, field, value))
        return cur.lastrowid
    else:
        return res[0]
```

However, I met this:
OperationalError: unrecognized token: "'''". It seems that my 2nd line of codes is incorrect.
I can not figure out why, so I do the same thing:

```
cu.execute("select rowid from urllist where %s = '%s'" % ('url', 'yes'))
```

It came out without an error. Why? How could I fix it?

Comment: Most likely, you had a relative of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) access your program, inputting apostrophe for your value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *parameterize the query*. You cannot though parameterize the table and field names, you can use string formatting to insert the table and field names into the query, but make sure you either trust the source, or validate the values properly:

```
query = "select rowid from {table} where {field} = %s".format(table=table, field=field)
cur = self.con.execute(query, (value, ))
res = cur.fetchone()
```

The parameterization not only helps to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, but also handles the data types conversions, escapes the parameters properly, which may fix your current problem as well.

Comment: I met OperationalError: near "%": syntax error on `cur = self.con.execute(query, (value, ))` after i changed. Why is that?